# When can pokemon forget HM Moves in XY?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I tought one of my pokemon Strength to test if I could erase it with another TM. Turns out that no, you still have to do something special to forget HM moves just like prior generations.

How can I forget HM moves in Pokemon X/Y?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - having the same answer does not a dupe make. There could be other ways in gen 6 of forgetting HM moves, aside from the move deleter (the fact that there isn't is not the relevant point)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you have access to [Dendemille Town](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Dendemille_Town), Sycamore will approach you beside a house.  That house, which is near the Pokemon Center, is the house where the [Move Deleter](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Move_Deleter) is.  Talk to him and he will delete one of your Pokemon's moves.

Comment: It is worth noting the same house has the Move Relearner as well.

Comment: Also, one must give [Move Relearner](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Move_Relearner) a [Heart Scale](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Heart_Scale) to re-learn any moves.

Answer (score 2):

The Move Deleter can be found in the house northeast of the Pokemon Center in Dendemille Town along with the Move Relearner. The Deleter is the old man on the left and the Relearner is the old woman on the right.

Comment: You also need heart scales....

Comment: You do not need Heart Scales to delete/forget moves.